# Possible to do two Group Bys and an if count check in one LINQ lambda statement?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda

Kind of a specific question but I wasn't sure how to approach it. I've got a list of rooms, that I am trying to group first by type, then by owner. I am doing this to check if there are duplicate rooms for a given owner and type (which shouldn't be possible so I need to prune them out). Right now my code looks like this:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<Guid, Room>> allRoomsByOwner = _dbContext.Rooms.GroupBy(x => x.OwnerId);
        List<Room> duplicates = new List<Room>();
        foreach (IGrouping<Guid, Room> roomsByOwner in allRoomsByOwner)
        {
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<Guid, Room>> roomsOfOwnerByType = roomsByOwner.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.TypeId);
            foreach (IGrouping<Guid, Room> grouping in roomsOfTypeByType)
            {
                if (grouping.Count() > 1)
                {
                    duplicates.AddRange(grouping.ToList());
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm just wondering if it's possible to put this all into one LINQ statement? I've got similar things before, but not quite this complex and not using two group bys. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by multiple columns ( `OwnerId` and `TypeId`) and flatten the groups with more than one elements (using the `SelectMany` method) to get the duplicates:

```
var duplicates = _dbContext.Rooms.GroupBy(x => new{x.OwnerId,x.TypeId})
                                 .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
                                 .SelectMany(g=>g.Skip(1))// If you like you can skip the first element as representative of the group and the treat the rest as a duplicate.
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: So I remove skip if i want to select both duplicates? But otherwise that will do the same as the code above?

Comment: If you remove the `Skip` you are going to select all the elements of each group that have more than one element, and yes if you remove the `Skip` you should get the same result